# ninject ioc with inherited base generic repository

Tags: ioc-container, ninject.web.mvc

I have a generic repository, abstract and concrete as below

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class

public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

I then have an repository that inherits from this, again abstract and concrete

```
public interface ISkyDiveCentreRepository : IGenericRepository<DiveCentre>

public class SkyDiveCentreRepository : GenericRepository<DiveCentre>
```

In my ninject config I then have

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
kernel.Bind<ISkyDiveCentreRepository>().To<SkyDiveCentreRepository>();
```

This is the first time I've tried to do this but am getting the error:

```
Error   2   The type 'UKSkyDiveCentres.DAL.imp.SkyDiveCentreRepository' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<T1>.To<TImplementation>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'SkyDiveCentres.DAL.imp.SkyDiveCentreRepository' to 'SkyDiveCentres.DAL.ISkyDiveCentreRepository'. C:SOMEPATH\UKSkyDiveCentres\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs   56  13  SkyDiveCentres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SkyDiveCentreRepository` inherits from `GenericRepository<DiveCentre>` and doesn't implement the `ISkyDiveCentreRepository` interface.

Simply explicitly implement it:

```
public class SkyDiveCentreRepository : 
    GenericRepository<DiveCentre>, ISkyDiveCentreRepository
                               //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this
```

Without it.. you can't do simple things like this:

```
ISkyDiveCentreRepository repo = new SkyDiveCentreRepository();
```

If you can't do it.. Ninject can't either.

Comment: Argghh!! Excellent that's done the trick, always good to get some fresh eyes on things!!